# Is it worth splitting one collection into many in MongoDB to speed up querying records?

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I have a query for a collection. I am filtering by one field. I thought, I can **speed up** query, if based on this field I **make many separate collections**, which collection's name would contain that field name, in previous approach I filtered with. Practically I could remove filter component in a query, because I need only pick the right collection and return documents in it as response. But in this way ducoments will be stored redundantly, a document earlier was stored only once, now document might be stored in more collections. Is this approach worth to follow? I use `Heroku` as cloud provider. By increasing of the number of dynos, it is easy to serve more user request. As I know read operations in `MongoDB` are highly mutual, parallel executed. Locking occure on document level. Is it possible gain any advantage by increasing redundancy? Of course index exists for that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's still within the same server, I believe there may be little parallelization gain (from the database side) in doing it this way, because for a single server, it matters little how your document is logically structured.

All the server cares about is how many collection and indexes you have, since it stores those collections and associated indexes in a number of files. It will need to load these files as the collection is accessed.

What could potentially be an issue is if you have a massive number of collections as a result, where you could hit the open file limit. Note that the open file limit is also shared with connections, so with a lot of collections, you're indirectly reducing the number of possible connections.

For illustration, let's say you have a big collection with e.g. 5 indexes on them. The WiredTiger storage engine stores the collection as:

- 1 file containing the collection data
- 1 file containing the `_id` index
- 5 files containing the 5 secondary indexes

Total = 7 files.

Now you split this one collection across e.g. 100 collections. Assuming the collections also requires 5 secondary indexes, in total they will need 700 files in WiredTiger (vs. of the original 7). This may or may not be desirable from your ops point of view.

If you require more parallelization if you're hitting some ops limit, then sharding is the recommended method. Sharding the busy collection across many different shards (servers) will immediately give you better parallelization vs. a single server/replica set, given a properly chosen [shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/) designed to maximize parallelization.

Having said that, sharding also requires more infrastructure and may complicate your backup/restore process. It will also require considerable planning and testing to ensure your design is optimal for your use case, and will scale well into the future.